# FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error

Tags: apex

I am getting the subjected error while executing Trigger and Apex class. Basically I am trying to update a text field using a String and I am getting the error :

> 18:46:42:423 FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error.

Below are the codes

**Trigger**

```
trigger Assigner on Incident__c (after update) {

    Incident__c[] inc = Trigger.new;
    system.debug(inc[0].Id);
    UpdateAssignee.getter(inc[0].Id);

}
```

**Apexclass**

```
public class UpdateAssignee {

    public static void getter(Id inc2)
    {
    String comp1, comp2;// Defined 2 strings
        Incident__c assign1 = [SELECT  EmailID__c,Assignee_Name__c FROM Incident__c WHERE Id=: inc2 LIMIT 1];
        comp1 = assign1.EmailID__c; //Assigned a text field value to a String
      Static_Data__c assign2 = [SELECT  Assignee_Name__c FROM Static_Data__c WHERE EmailID__c=: comp1 LIMIT 1]; 
        comp2 = assign2.Assignee_Name__c;
        Incident__c assign3;
        try {
        assign3 = [SELECT  Assignee_Name__c FROM Incident__c WHERE Id=: inc2 LIMIT 1];
          assign3.Assignee_Name__c = comp2;
          update assign3;    
         } catch(DmlException e) {
                  System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem i see is somehow in after update trigger you are trying to update same record causing it go in recursion and throwing the salesforce Internal error .

Let me modify your trigger to before update trigger

```
trigger Assigner on Incident__c (before update) {
  Incident__c[] inc = Trigger.new;
  system.debug(inc[0].Id);
  UpdateAssignee.getter(inc[0]);
}
```

Your modified apex class

```
public class UpdateAssignee {

public static void getter(Incident__c  inc2){
    String comp1, comp2;// Defined 2 strings
    comp1 = inc2.EmailID__c; //Assigned a text field value to a String
    Static_Data__c assign2 = [SELECT  Assignee_Name__c FROM Static_Data__c WHERE EmailID__c=: comp1 LIMIT 1]; 
      comp2 = assign2.Assignee_Name__c;
      inc2.Assignee_Name__c = comp2;  
     } 
  }
}
```

Also I noticed you have not bulkified your trigger class .Please bulkify this as this wont run when a load is made.You will need to use maps and sets for bulk ifications .

Comment: Mohith, Thanks for your answer. I will try this. Actually I have just started up APEX coding. Will try the above suggestion and come back if any error/concerns.